# dequeueResusableCellWithIdentifier not returning custom cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to use a custom cell in a tableview configured independently of storyboards and nibs.

Whenever I use the tableview's dequeuing method, the cells come back as standard, run of the mill cells. Yet if i don't use the dequeuing, the cells come back as expected, that is, customized. Here's what doesnt seem to be working:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView registerClass:[FloatingGradientCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    FloatingGradientCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[FloatingGradientCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier topGradientColor:[UIColor blackColor] bottomGradientColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    MWFeedItem *article = [_articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = article.title;

    return cell;
}
```

This, however, IS working. . . .

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    FloatingGradientCell *cell = [[FloatingGradientCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell" topGradientColor:[UIColor lightTextColor] bottomGradientColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    MWFeedItem *article = [_articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = article.title;

    return cell;
}
```

Any ideas what exactly is going on here?

thanks!

Comment: From the docs: "If you registered a class for the specified identifier and a new cell must be created, this method initializes the cell by calling its initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: method. For nib-based cells, this method loads the cell object from the provided nib file. If an existing cell was available for reuse, this method calls the cell’s prepareForReuse method instead." . . . so how can I set the appropriate properties .. .

Comment: Just to be clear, if you're not using a Storyboard or Nib, you're creating the TableViewCell in code somewhere? Also, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will `init` the custom cell (and if it's in code then `loadView` will be called).

Comment: Ya the route I ended up taking was to implement the code I had in the custom initializiation wihtin the loadView. That seemed to work, although it didnt help the problem of giving the cell two arguments to work with before it loads . . .

Answer (score 3):

You are reregistering the class for every cell. You should register the custom cell somewhere else, like in your viewDidLoad.

Comment: moved that...still not working. However, i did just noticed that the if (cell == nil) never gets called so i'm never actually calling the initializer for my cell... i think i'm missing something with how the cell gets initialized in the first place